# how to run an large process in java on a button click

Tags: java, zk

i need to start an crawl process on clicking a button if i write inside onclick the other tabs cant be accessible till the process stops i need to run the process in background.in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call another thread inside the "on click" callback, like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {  
    public void run() {  
        // your code  
    }  
});  
t.start();
```

Comment: is it possible to stop that thread by re clicking that button

Comment: No. See here http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/31728. When you later run into weird behaviour, read all about synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

Start it in another Thread
[ref](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)
[example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/Threads.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing then this might be useful

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: This is not at all about Swing-like desktop development, there's a tag "zk" standing for ZK framework - web based one. Please pay attention to question. And swing wouldn't be accessible if you deploy on google apps cloud platform, but zk could be used there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "concurrent" package from Java 5:

[java.util.concurrent package summary](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

and, in particular, a thread pool. This would be more robust, since if you couldn't handle thread termination correctly or will occasionally leave it alive you could have a resource leak.